# Quel pronom utiliser dans les constructions de type « verbe + de + une personne » ?

Tags: pronoms

- Je parlais **de mes problèmes**. → J’**en** parlais.
- Je parlais **de mes parents**. → Je parlais **d’eux**.
- Je me moquais **du garçon**. → Je me moquais **de lui**.

Dans la première phrase on remplace *de + une chose* par *en*. Cela, c’est clair. Pourtant, quand *de* est suivi d’une personne, j’ai appris qu’il faut remplacer la partie en gras par *de + un pronom tonique*.

De temps en temps je vois qu’on utilise *en* aussi pour remplacer *de + une personne*. Alors, est-ce que les formes suivantes sont possibles ou même préférées ?

- Je parlais **de mes parents**. → J’**en** parlais.
- Je me moquais **du garçon**. → Je m’**en** moquais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Réserver *en* aux antécédents qui sont des choses est une règle qui décrit mal l'usage qui admet facilement des personnes pour antécédents avec les verbes exprimant un sentiment, une sensation, un mouvement et d'autres comme : parler de; dire de; obtenir de; recevoir de, tirer de, s'occuper de, faire de. (Voir le deuxième onglet de l'[entrée du TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/en) qui a une remarque à ce sujet à la fin du point I.A.)

Answer (score 2):

Both are OK, but "J'en parle" is kinda undefined, so if the wording of your sentence makes the usage of "en" ambiguous, it's better to use "Je parle d'eux" or "Je parle d'elle"...

Example:

Mon petit frère tire les cheveux de ma petite soeur et je m'en moque.

Who are you mocking? The little brother? The little sister? The fact that he is pulling her hair? Following the grammatical rules, you should refer to the last "antecedant", that is the last possible solution in the sentence (=the sister). But that's not what you mean: really, you want to mock the little brother. So you remove the ambiguity by saying:

"Mon petit frère tire les cheveux de ma petite soeur et je me moque de lui."

Answer (score 0):

Il me semble que pour *à*, il n'y ait pas de règle qui permette une réponse claire, mis à part connaître comment se comporte chaque verbe:

> Je succède à Bernard -> Je lui succède
>
> Je pense à Bernard -> J'y pense

Pour moi, ça doit être la même chose pour *de*.